# Subscript out of range, Excel VBA, Trying to create an array within a loop

Tags: excel, vba, range, subscript

I'm trying to loop through all the controls in my form and for each time it catches a Label, the Tag element of the Label is added into the array.

```
Dim labelCounter As Integer
labelCounter = 0
Dim arrayTag() As String

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctl)
        Case "Label"
        arrayTag(labelCounter) = ctl.Tag
        labelCounter = labelCounter + 1
    End Select
Next
```

I keep getting the Subscript out of range error. What's going wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of labelCounter when it falls over?  Have you got Option Base set to 1?

Comment: Where is the code residing inside the userform or in a separate module. If the latter don't use `Me` use the actual form name

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim labelCounter As Integer
    Dim arrayTag() As String
    Dim ct As String, ctl

    labelCounter = 0
    ReDim arrayTag(0 To labelCounter)
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        ct = TypeName(ctl)
        If ct = "Label" Then
            If labelCounter > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve arrayTag(0 To labelCounter)
            End If
            arrayTag(labelCounter) = ctl.Tag
            labelCounter = labelCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Debug.Print Join(arrayTag, ",")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your only issue is you created an array (arrayTag) without specifying how many elements are in it.  As far as I recall, when creating an array you need to either A.) Specify the number of elements in it, or B.) Create an array the way you did (With empty parenthesis) and then `ReDim` it once you reach a point in the code execution where you know how many elements are in it.  I think you can also `ReDim Preserve` to change the size of the array without deleting its contents.

```
Dim labelCounter As Integer
labelCounter = 0
Dim arrayTag(50) As String

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctl)
        Case "Label"
        arrayTag(labelCounter) = ctl.Tag
        labelCounter = labelCounter + 1
    End Select
Next
```